# Nav Controller issue with Unit tests and Hilt

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dagger-hilt

in my fragment I have:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val navController = view.findNavController()
    ...
}
```

I have extension function to lunch fragment in my custom Activity:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    themeResId: Int = androidx.fragment.testing.R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
    crossinline action: T.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val mainActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra("androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY", themeResId)

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(mainActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        fragmentFactory?.let {
            activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
            activity.setTheme(themeResId)
        }
        val fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs

        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()

        (fragment as T).action()
    }

}
```

and a test:

```
@Test    
fun test(){
        val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<TypeAddFragment> {
            TypeAddFragment().also { fragment->
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner->
                    if(viewLifecycleOwner != null){
                        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
                    }
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

all I get is an error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView{78283f9 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} does not have a NavController set
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:71)
at androidx.navigation.ViewKt.findNavController(View.kt:28)
at com.rachapps.homewine.ui.fragment.TypeAddFragment.onViewCreated(TypeAddFragment.kt:49)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1808)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1720)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
at com.rachapps.homewine.viewModel.TypeAddViewModelTest$temp_test$$inlined$launchFragmentInHiltContainer$default$1.perform(HiltExt.kt:41)
at com.rachapps.homewine.viewModel.TypeAddViewModelTest$temp_test$$inlined$launchFragmentInHiltContainer$default$1.perform(HiltExt.kt:28)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:660)

Comment: Did you find any solution?